# Dragging a CSS rotated div

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop, rotation

I am creating a drag and drop utility which allows you to drag / drop, turn and rotate some 'cubes' in a grid. Each cube has six sides that you can switch between, and I'm using a using a background image and repositioning this in CSS. This is all fine, but if the element is rotated in CSS then when I come to drag this, the dragged clone [if that's what it's called] is displaying as untransformed.

I've uploaded a simple JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rxd0kgcs/6/ - I've put the code here:

CSS

```
.cube0 {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cube1 {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  top: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  transform:rotate(90deg); 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); 
  -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); 
  -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='cube0' id='cube0' style='background-image: 
url("http://media9.cagd.co.uk/835/1818706_5c3742f.gif");' 
draggable='true'></div>
<div class='cube1' id='cube1' style='background-image: 
url("http://media9.cagd.co.uk/835/1818706_5c3742f.gif");' 
draggable='true'></div>
```

Please let me know if I've left anything out - and thanks in advance!
Ben

Comment: What you left out is a [mcve] **within the question itself**.

Comment: Thanks, Rob - I'm new to posting on SO! Would you like me to put the contents of the JSFiddle in here? I'll do that until advised otherwise.